# Removing HTML tag property within an attribute using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to remove a particular property from a HTML string.

Here is my sample HTML string.

```
<span lang=EN-GB style='font-size:10.0pt;line-height:115%;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";color:#17365D'>Thank you</span>
```

Is there any way to remove the **line-height:115%;** property from the string, which would have provide me the output as below by using Regex in C#.net?

```
<span lang=EN-GB style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";color:#17365D'>Thank you</span>
```

I have tried with this Regex, but it just removed all of the **style** attribute, but what I am trying to achieve here is to remove only the **line-height** property.

```
Regex.Replace(html, @"<([^>]*)(?:style)=(?:'[^']*'|""[^""]*""|[^\s>]+)([^>]*)>", "<$1$2>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I just need to match the **line-height** property in the **style** attribute without caring about the value it has and remove the whole line till the end of semicolon(;). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just checking that opening the HTML in notepad with find/replace isnt an option?

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: I would recommend you to use a DOM parser instead of regular expressions. Regex is not recommended when dealing with html/xml.

Comment: If you want to post code, edit your question instead of posting it in comments - it will be way more readable.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex summons tainted souls into the realm of the living. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Jite: As applicable as this advise is in the general case, wouldn't you say that this depends on context? If this is a quick find/replace through a limited set of files he has control over himself, would you still recommend that he uses a DOM parser?

Comment: Hi, I think therre's a little misunderstanding here. What I am trying to do here is to remove certain attribute from the string during runtime.

Comment: @steinar That depends, if its only this line (and thats all the input) that he would want to remove a known string from, no, a parser might be a bit too much.
Else, yes, probably.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using HtmlAgilityPack for this instead of using Regex.

Excuse me for the below example is a lil messy(but works) just to give you an idea of this.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("<span lang=EN-GB style='font-size:10.0pt;line-height:115%;font-family:\"Tahoma\",\"sans-serif\";color:#17365D'>Thank you</span>");

foreach (var item in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("span"))
{
    var temp = item.Attributes["style"];
    var styles = temp.Value.Split(';').ToList();
    var newStyleList = styles.Where(m => !m.Contains("line-height:115%")).ToList();
    string newStyle = string.Empty;
    foreach (var style in newStyleList)
    {
        newStyle += style + ";";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone for your kind suggestion. I have figured out a Regex for this situation. Here's it if anyone is interested. Thank you.

```
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"line-height:[^;]+;", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```